# Using Bing API: easiest way to connect with an API and get data from it

Tags: c#, asp.net, bing-api

I've searched some time, looking for easy way to connect with some other sites WebAPI. There are some solutions, but they are made in very complicated way.

What I want to do:

1. Connect with server using URL adress
2. Provide login and password to get some data
3. Get data as JSON/XML
4. Save this data in an "easy-to-read" way. I mean: save it to C# variable which could be easy to modify.

Currently, API that I want to work with is Bing Search, but I'm looking for some universal way. I found [an example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/How-to-use-bing-search-API-4c8b287e), but it doesn't work for me and in my app I can't use this class: "DataServiceQuery" because it doesn't exsist.

How do you usually do it? Do you have your favourite solutions? Are there some universal ways or it depends on type of API that you work with?

I'm currently working on .NET MVC app (in case it could make any difference)

Answer (score 1):

**From server side**

You can use that like below.

```
// Create an HttpClient instance 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 

// Send a request asynchronously continue when complete 
client.GetAsync(_address).ContinueWith( 
      (requestTask) => 
     { 
          // Get HTTP response from completed task. 
          HttpResponseMessage response = requestTask.Result; 

          // Check that response was successful or throw exception 
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 

           // Read response asynchronously as JsonValue
          response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonArray>().ContinueWith( 
                (readTask) => 
                { 
                    var result = readTask.Result
                    //Do something with the result                   
                }); 
     });
```

You can see example on following link.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee

**For JavaScirpt:**
You could use jQuery and WebAPI both together to do your stuff.

There are few steps to it.

1. Call web api with Ajax jquery call.
2. Get reponse in JSON
3. Write javascript code to manipulate that response and do your stuff.

This is the easiest way.

See following link for reference:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424461/Implementing-Consuming-ASP-NET-WEB-API-from-JQuery

Comment: I want to do everything on server side. So JavaScript is not the solution here

Comment: Then why you want to use webapi?

Comment: Bing search engine provides an api that allows me to search for some things and receive results directly on my server. I want to use this API to add some functionality that rely on Bing Search Engine

Comment: @Ludwik11, you mean to say, you want to make WebApi call from `serverside`?

Comment: @MokshShah I mean I want to use BingAPI in my .NET MVC app

Comment: Can you provide some sample URL?

Comment: @MokshShah Searching for "apple" using Bing https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27apple%27

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama "HttpClient could not be found" says Visual Studio, does it work on .NET?

Comment: @ Ludwik11 you need to use System.net.http namesapce. See following link for another way.

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama And do "JsonArray" is an built-in class or this is class that I have to create by myself?

Comment: @Yes it is. Download example link I have provided. There is a source code also attached with it in answer.

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama sorry for that many questions but I have to ask again ^^ To get data from Bing API I have to provide "Primary Account Key". How can I send it with request?

Comment: I have not implemented it but you can see following link for your reference-http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43419/Basics-of-Bing-Search-API-using-NET

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/integrate-bing-api-for-search-inside-asp-net-web-application

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on the type of API you want to use. From a .Net point of view, there could be `.Net 2 Web Services`, `WCF Services` and `Web API Services`.

Web APIs today are following the REST standard and RMM. Some APIs need API Keys provided as url parameters, others require you to put in request's header. Even some more robust APIs, use authentication schemes such as OAuth 2. And some companies have devised their own standards and conventions.

So, the short answer is that *there is no universal way*. The long answer comes from documentation of each API and differs from one to another.